# statistical test for 3-preference choice design

Tags: multinomial-distribution, choice-modeling

We collected data from 40 animals in which we recorded the total time the animal spent in each of the 3 possible chambers.  Thus, for each animal, we have three times (one for each chamber) and those 3 times add up to 10 minutes.  Does anyone have any recommendations on statistical test that incorporates the magnitude of the differences in times?  Much thanks.

Comment: Maybe an exact test.